# javascript variable value as a link

Tags: javascript

I have a variable and I would like to add a link for its value. This below example only returns the html. How can I make this a clickable link when its returned?

```
var link = 'new link: <a href="http://test.com/" target="_blank"><b>Clink Here</font></b></a>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
var link = 'new link: <a href="http://test.com/" target="_blank"><b>Clink Here</font></b></a>'
myDiv.innerHTML = link;
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

For the id:

```
myDiv.id = "myLink";
alert(document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML);
```

Comment: thanks also how would i assign an id to that div being created?

Answer (score 0):

You need a container where the HTML will be placed.  If you can use jQuery, this becomes very easy.

```
<div id="container"></div>

var link = '...';
$('#container').html(link);
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mEjUg/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$("<div />")
    .html('new link: <a href="http://test.com/" target="_blank"><b>Click Here</b></a>')
    .appendTo("body");
```